# How To: Auto Resize GridPanel Column Width + Read all Column Values in a Grid in Ext JS4

Tags: javascript, extjs4, gridpanel

**How To: Auto Resize GridPanel Column Width + Read all Column Values in a Grid in Ext JS4**

Problem 1: Is there anyway I can automatically set gridpanel column width,
based on retruned column data values length (column width = max data value
string length)

Problem 2: To achive above (and for other reasons), I need to know how i can get values of
particular grid column? Once i know the logic, should implement it as column
renderer function? Would column renderer function is called every time, a data
record is read (then its overkill)?, in that case is there any other function I can override?

Most of the solutions (Grid Column Width Calculator,
autoResizeColumns,etc) I find on the web are for previous versions, am using EXTJS 4 version.

Thanks in advance
Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Unfortunately, no. Your best bet would be to set specified widths for data that was generally fixed, and then set the other columns using `flex`. (or write / wait for a plugin).
2. Values are not stored in the `grid`, they are in the `grid`'s `store`. You would simply need to loop the `store` in question and grab all the values from the specified column. For example:

   ```
   Ext.Array.each(Ext.StoreManager.get('myStore').getRange(0), function(record){
       console.log(record.get("myColumnName")); 
   });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

There is actually an Extjs 4 plugin to automatically resize grid columns based on the width of the contents as well as the header.

Here is the link: [Extjs 4 column auto resize plugin](http://dnorman.github.com/ExtJS-Patches/example/ColumnAutoWidthPlugin.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a temporary fix to wrap Columns using CSS, as described here:
[ExtJS 4 - Wrapping the column headers in grid panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361512/extjs-4-wrapping-the-column-headers-in-grid-panel)

### Add the following to ext js css

```
.x-column-header-inner {
    line-height: normal;
    padding-top: 3px !important;
    padding-bottom: 3px !important;
    text-align: center;
    top: 20%;
}

.x-column-header-inner .x-column-header-text {
    white-space: normal;
}
```