# ExtJS 4 - Wrapping the column headers in grid panel

Tags: extjs, header, grid, extjs4

I have a grid which has long phrases as header texts. These texts are never displayed properly in the available width for the column.

Is there any way these texts can be wrapped and limited to the column width?

Here is an image of the issue:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give this a shot in your CSS:

```
.x-grid3-hd-inner {
     overflow: hidden;
     padding: 3px 3px 3px 5px;
     white-space: normal;
}
```

And additionally, another option if the first doesn't work:

```
.x-column-header-inner .x-column-header-text {
    white-space: normal;
}

.x-column-header-inner {
    line-height: normal;
    padding-top: 3px !important;
    padding-bottom: 3px !important;
    text-align: center;
    top: 20%;
}
```

Comment: Hi dmackerman

Thanks for sharing the hack. The first solution is unfortunately not working but the second one is working perfectly in Mozilla. But in IE (IE9 I checked) its not able to have any effect. 

Any suggestions. Thanks again.

Comment: Remove the top:20% if you click on the header to do a sort, for some reason it pushes the header text down afterwards.